# is this sentence correct? "he felt that he must first excel in history."

Tags: sentence-construction

is this sentence correct:

> Clarence Darrow wanted to become a prominent lawyer, but he felt that
>   **he must first excel in history.**

i have a feeling that the correct form of the sentence should be something like this:

> Clarence Darrow wanted to become a prominent lawyer, but he felt that **he had to first exceled in history.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is perfectly fine, if somewhat formal sounding:

> Clarence Darrow wanted to become a prominent lawyer, but he felt that he must first excel in history.

Your second sentence has two problems: "excelled" is misspelled, and it is not correct to use past-tense for something that has yet to be done.

This version would be OK because "Had to" and "Must" are synonyms:

> Clarence Darrow wanted to become a prominent lawyer, but he felt that he had to first excel in history.

Comment: Are you sure about your spelling statement?  "excelled" is the the only listed form in both Merriam Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excel and Oxford https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/excel

Comment: what's the grammatical explanation for "future in past" with "Must" ?